# A generic error occurred in GDI+System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException HResult=0x80004005 Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, image, save, box

I'm trying to save an image in picture box to a path on another computer in the LAN. It give me this error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+
```

It works for some jpg files and not for others.

I'm getting the following error message:

```
string pathFolder = "\\\\DESKTOP-PDP6PSF\\Data\\daily\\";
picturebox1.Image.Save(pathFolder+nameImage1+".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Save them as PNG instead.

Comment: Should you actually need a JPG format, you can save the Image to a MemoryStream, then use the [ImageCodecInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo).[GetImageEncoders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo.getimageencoders) method, specifying the JPG Encoder and save the Image as JPG with parameters. Or take the Image and draw it to a Bitmap and then save it as JPG (the first method is better, you can control the quality and the compression level).

Comment: thank you very much Jimi, firs method was okay for me :)))

Comment: @Jimi That doesn't really answer the question on why this crashes, though, and, due to that, it does not seem to me like a guaranteed solution.

Comment: @Nyerguds  If fact it's a comment, not an answer :) Anyway, the generic GDI+ exception + the PictureBox.Image converted to JPG from-nobody-knows-what, it's quite the clue. It's not the missing write permission thing, since it sometimes works. It's not the too early disposed stream thing. It doesn't look like the web page accessing a network path in a weird way thing. You're left with a couple of possibilities. The JPG Encoder thing was the most probable cause (given the little context in this question).

Comment: @Jimi I honestly _never_ heard of any case of the jpeg encoder itself failing, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced `0x80004005` too.

It seems GDI+ has some trouble with storing to a path, regardless whether that path is in the local FS or network.

Save to a temporary `MemoryStream` instead, then persist that to the path.